# Deprecated DefaultHttpClient and StringBody in Android

Tags: php, android, apache

I send a `XML` File via `URL` to an PHP-Server.

Yesterday I changed the compiledSdkVersion from 17 to 23

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

and after I rebuild the project it says me that the `DefaultHttpClient` Method is deprecated.

This is the Code:

```
String sURL = "http://www.example.com/function?f=1000&";
String returnString;
File fileDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "job_active");
fileDir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(fileDir,filename);

try {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(sURL);


    MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    //Füge die Datei zur Entity hinzu
    multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
    //Füge den Dateinamen hinzu
    multipartEntity.addPart("tmp_name", new StringBody(FilewithoutExt));

    httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    //Bekomme die Antwort vom Server zurück
    returnString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Another deprecated Method is the `StringBody` method.

I've seen an example in other Threads like:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

But I can't find a way to replace those two methods. Can I use the `HttpUrlConnection` and send a file with it?

I hope it's clear what my problem is.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` into `android` tag in your apps gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file using HttpURLConnection.

More details : http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106